# loading dynamic uploaded images outside assets folder

Tags: angular, spring-boot

using **assets** folder to show images is done with static path.
How ever it's not the case when using dynamic path because `ng serve` loads the application in memory and the new added item , let say image for example cannot be loaded in the current compiled application.

so after googling, the workaround is using another folder let say **outsideUploades**.
and on the file **angular.json**, I made:

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {"glob": "**/*", "input": "../outsideUploades ", "output": "./assets/upload"}  // I added that
          ]
```

I have [this architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUUuu.png)

so, I changed the path of uploded images to go to **outsideUploades** folder.
but when I made:

```
<img id="dynamicPathFromOutsideUploades" src="{{getDynamicPath()}}" style="max-width:50px">
```

with

```
getDynamicPath()
{
    return this.user.displayPathImage; // that returns   C:\$. REFONTE\upload\img1.jpg 
}
```

I can't show the desired images.

Have you please any idea about solving that.
Big thanks.

Comment: What is your stored addressed? Means what is the value of `this.user.displayPathImage`

Comment: Hello Sir @SavanPadaliya, thanks a lot for your replay. the value is `C:\$. REFONTE\upload\img1.jpg` as I commented in my question.

Comment: Does you required image is stored in that directory?

Comment: Yes Sir, once I uploaded the image, it's stored on that directory `C:\$. REFONTE\upload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that's why you should using server-side path instead,
I'm talking about the resulted url from rest api, for example `http://localhost:6227/api/auth/files/img1.jpg`, after that, you call it in your function on client-side.

Hope To Help